# Angular Structural Directive Broken

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I'm trying to create a site using Angular 5.2.9. I'm working through building a system to log in to and now want to avoid loading elements into the page when the user isn't authorized.

Routes is one thing, I can use the canActivate and put the AuthGuard in there, but for specific elements (like menu items, page elements) I want to control whether the user sees them. So, I thought I would create a structural directive.

I copied the example code directly into my application from the [Angular Documentation](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives). While typing I get the error;

> Property binding appUnless not used by any directive on an embedded
>   template. Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and
>   all directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations".

I have the directive referenced in my declarations inside of app.module.ts. I'm certain I'm missing something, but I'm not quite sure what. I've looked all around here and other places.

Comment: are you using the asterisk syntax (`*appUnless`) or the expanded `<ng-template [appUnless]` syntax? I can only get the `*` syntax working myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copy and paste the app.module.ts file from the `angular documentation` below.

You forgot to add `declarations: [UnlessDirective]` to your project. That's the reason you are getting the error. `UnlessDirective` should be replaced by your directive name.

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent }         from './app.component';
import { heroSwitchComponents } from './hero-switch.components';
import { UnlessDirective }    from './unless.directive';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    heroSwitchComponents,
    UnlessDirective
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: I have it in my app.module.ts, I'm still getting the error. If it works for you, I have to be missing something.

Comment: Did you import all the modules?

Comment: Thank you!. I'm really wet behind the ears with Angular. Basically, the area I was trying to put it in was from a layout I purchased. The layout had be broken down into sub modules. I was putting the directive in the main module, but not the sub module I was trying to use it in. Lesson learned.